# Synonyms for "unfortunately"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Are there any words for *unfortunately*?
I know that "sad" is a wrong replacement, but I don't know any other words for it. I write this word just way too much and it would be nice to have an alternative.

For example :

> I would send you a post card, but unfortunately I don't have your new
>   address.

or :

> I unfortunately can't give you the information. I am sorry.

Thanks.

Comment: 'I'm sorry to say' is used as a bland replacement for 'unfortunately': neither implies you're devastated, sorrowful, too bothered. 'Sadly' used here is almost as bland, unlike its role in say 'Sadly, he was killed in the second battle'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unluckily, regrettably or alas** may fit your sentence.

Comment: _Regrettably_, spot on. _Unluckily_, not so good. _Alas_, whimsical, and probably inappropriate for someone whose address you don't have. Still worth +1 for 'regrettably'.

Comment: + 1 for your ' I am sorry to say' :)

Comment: As bad luck would have it

Answer (score 0):

**I'm afraid** I can't help you with this,